# Font.getTextAttributes Map error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to CAP#1

Tags: java, generics, fonts

I am trying to enable font ligatures:

```
Map attrs = font.getAttributes();
attrs.put(TextAttribute.LIGATURES, TextAttribute.LIGATURES_ON);
font = font.deriveFont(attrs);
```

Notice that `Map` is not typechecked and the compiler gives a warning:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type Map
```

which is fair, but how do I fix it?
`getAttributes` returns `Map<TextAttribute, ?>` (holding values of arbitrary types) thus trying the following:

```
Map<TextAttribute, ?> attrs = font.getAttributes();
attrs.put(TextAttribute.LIGATURES, TextAttribute.LIGATURES_ON);
font = font.deriveFont(attrs);
```

Now the compiler issues an error:

```
error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to CAP#1
```

So the first argument is typechecked fine, and I do not expect to typecheck the second argument (we are using `?` here after all -- anything can happen and that's the whole point of this map).

Is there a way to please the compiler typechecker?
Note that I cannot change the API, maybe there is a way to say `I know what I am doing here`?

Answer (score 1):

`deriveFont()` will retain the existing attributes, so you are not required to do `getAttributes` first.

Below snippet shows it.

```java
Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN,20);
System.out.println(font.getAttributes()); // Prints map of {family="Courier", weight=1.0*, width=1.0*, posture=0.0*, size=20.0, transform=null*, superscript=0*, tracking=0.0*[btx=null, ctx=null]}

HashMap<TextAttribute, Object> attrs = new HashMap<>();
attrs.put(TextAttribute.LIGATURES, TextAttribute.LIGATURES_ON);
font = font.deriveFont(attrs);
System.out.println(font.getAttributes()); //Prints map of map of {family="Courier", weight=1.0*, width=1.0*, posture=0.0*, size=20.0, transform=null*, superscript=0*, ligatures=1, tracking=0.0*[btx=null, ctx=null]}
```

---

Ideally, if clients are expected to add entries to a collection, it will not have the parameter type `?`.

But in case, if such a scenario arises, the best option I could think of is to cast the return type and suppress the warning as below:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
Map<TextAttribute, Object> attrs = (Map<TextAttribute, Object>) font.getAttributes();
attrs.put(TextAttribute.LIGATURES, TextAttribute.LIGATURES_ON);
font = font.deriveFont(attrs);
```

Thanks